# JSON Data and Terminology - Simple vs Complex

Tags: json

Is there any difference in how we define/label JSON data?  For example, JSON data can contain simple `Key : Value` pairs but it can also contain String Arrays and contain nested JSON Array objects.  When the JSON objects become 'Complex' what is the terminology (if any) used to describe these objects.  How do I speak intelligently about these differences if the terminology exists to do so?  For now I'm simply calling these objects 'Simple' or 'Complex' and perhaps that will do but I am curious if the community even makes the distinction.

Example of a Simple JSON Object:

> `{"name": "Jason", "age": 31, "phone": "555-666-1234"}`

Example of what I would consider to be a Complex JSON Object

> `{"name": "Jason", "age": 31, "phone": ["555-666-1234", "415-515-8187"], "children": [{"name": "Jenny", "age": 5}, {"name": "Brian", "age": 8}]}`

So again, do we simply call each of these two examples `JSON Objects` or can we apply the terms `Simple` and `Complex` in order to define these as either a Simple or Complex JSON Object due to the String Array as well as the nested Children array that is in the complex example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `JSON` contains nested objects or arrays, it's a "complex type" or "complex".  If it contains key value pairs without nested objects or arrays, it's a "simple type" or "simple".

It's **not** incorrect to refer to the two examples you gave as JSON objects, as that is a broader descriptive term.  If you want to be more specific, you can add the qualifier "simple" or "complex".